# How to fusion cells of a dataframe by summation

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transform my dataframe by merging it cells and summing them into other larger cells given the indices of those, as an example, given the indices `[0,2] & [2,4]` on the `X` and `Y` axis and go from the following dataframe :

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
+----+----+----+----+
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

to the following one:

```
+----+----+
| 14 | 22 |
+----+----+
| 46 | 54 |
+----+----+
```

I was thinking of Pandas' `groupBY.transform` or `rolling` would be of help.
Any clues?

Comment: Is this pandas or polar? there is no `groupBY.transform` in pandas. unless you mean `groupby`

Comment: this is pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have homogenous blocks (e.g, 2x2), the most efficient would be
to [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the underlying [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) array and `sum`:

```
N = 2

out = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()
                     # convert the 2D array to 4D
                     .reshape(len(df)//N, N, -1, N)
                     # sum along dimensions 1 and 3 to go back to 2D
                     .sum((1, 3))
                   )
```

If you want non-square blocks (RxC):

```
R, C = 2, 2

out = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()
                     .reshape(len(df)//R, R, df.shape[1]//C, C)
                     .sum((1, 3))
                   )
```

Output:

```
    0   1
0  14  22
1  46  54
```

Intermediate 4D array:

```
# df.to_numpy().reshape((len(df)//N, N, -1, N))

array([[[[ 1,  2],    # ──┐
         [ 3,  4]],   # ─┐├─> 1+2+5+6 = 14
                      #  ││
        [[ 5,  6],    # ──┘
         [ 7,  8]]],  # ─┴──> 3+4+7+8 = 22


       [[[ 9, 10],    # ──┐
         [11, 12]],   # ─┐├─>  9+10+13+14 = 46
                      #  ││
        [[13, 14],    # ──┘
         [15, 16]]]]) # ─┴──> 11+12+15+16 = 54
```

###### shape is not a multiple of `N`

You need to pad the input to a multiple of `N`. For example using:

```
N = 3
X = int(np.ceil(df.shape[0]/N)*N)
Y = int(np.ceil(df.shape[1]/N)*N)
df = df.reindex(index=range(X), columns=range(Y), fill_value=0)
```

Then the aggregation code.

Comment: could you point out the website reference to reshape() with 4 params?

Comment: @marcnicole I should have pointed to the [`ndarray.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape) documentation page. I also used a shortcut `reshape(a,b,c,d)` while the way that is described in the documentation should have been `reshape((a,b,c,d))`. In the end, you pass a tuple with the requested shape. I updated the answer to show the intermediate

Comment: This is the way to go. amazing solution!

Comment: but reshaping a dataframe won't work here?

Comment: also what is sum(tuple) about?

Comment: `sum(tuple)` indicates to sum along those dimensions. It aggregates dimensions 1 and 3 of the intermediate 4D array into their sum, going back to 2D with a reduced shape.

Comment: what made you think to convert the problem into a numpy's through `df.to_numpy()`?

Comment: so N, C are the range of the input indices I mention in the question?

Comment: Because pandas is built on top of numpy. Here since you all an homogenous dtype, a DataFrame is nothing more than a 2D array with index/column names

Comment: R/C are the number of rows/cols of the blocks used to aggregate. N = R = C if the blocks are square (N=2 in your example)

Comment: But I mention that I need to pass the indices splitting the dataframe into parts to sum as input

Comment: @marcnicole but are your indices always evenly spaced? This was the assumption of all answerers. Can you provide a larger example?

Comment: evenly spaced yes

Comment: Then this is what the proposed approaches are doing, instead of passing all indices you only need to specify the step (`N`)

Comment: FOR SOme cases reshaping results in error, e.g reshaping 100*100 dataframe into a 3*3 one...

Comment: @marcnicole because 100 is not a multiple of 30. In this case you need to pad to the nearest multiple (see update)

Comment: on a dataset of 100 rows if the squares are defined using on the X and Y [0.33], [34,66], [67,99] would that yield 9 squares out of the initial dataframe? would that work with any input ranges and any dataframe ?

Answer (score 1):

```
def fn(x):
    x.index = x.columns = x.index//2
    y = x.stack().groupby(level = [0,1]).sum().unstack()
    y.index.name = y.columns.name = None
    return y

df = pd.DataFrame({0 : [1, 5, 9, 13], 1 : [2, 6, 10, 14],
              2 : [3, 7, 11, 15], 3 : [4, 8, 12, 16]})
fn(df.copy())
    0   1
0  14  22
1  46  54
```

Comment: You can simplify the code to `y = x.stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().unstack()` ;)

Comment: @mozway thanks alot for the simplification. Never thought could group directly by the index. Still alot to learn]

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension combined with `np.array_split` for faster code instead of a slower `for` loop :

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_len = len(df)//2

# Reshape the list into a 2x2 array
arr = np.array(   [arr2.sum().sum() for arr1 in np.array_split(df, df_len) 
                            for arr2 in np.array_split(arr1, df_len, axis=1)]
                  ).reshape((df_len, df_len))

# Convert the array to a DataFrame
result = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

print(result)
```

```
   col1  col2
0    14    22
1    46    54
```

**Timings**

Tested with `time_it` :

- Laurent_B :

```py
Temps d'exécution du script: 0.004486 secondes
```

- Mozway :

```py
Temps d'exécution du script: 0.000242 secondes
```

- Onyambu

```py
Temps d'exécution du script: 0.004269 secondes
```

In definitive, Mozway has the fastest script using pure numpy components, even if other approaches work too.

Comment: A list comprehension with `array_split` **is a python loop**. In fact a nested loop in your case. This is certainly not going to be faster than pure numpy, have you timed it? ;)

Comment: Dear, I like your posts not the fact that you spoil my day :-p... I agree with you but I have just said that it's faster than a `for` loop

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to spoil your day, I only wanted to discuss efficiency;) My point is that your approach **is** a `for` loop. I would even bet that it is slower than a pure python loop directly on the indices without `array_split` (I'd really be interested to see the timings) :p

Comment: That was difficult to write but it's done :-/

Comment: coding is also about making the code easy to understand and straightforward (not only about efficiency)